# Jquery - How to get the selector of a plugin call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Being a Noob at Jquery, I'll ask a noob question.
How do you get the selector of a plugin call inside the plugin?

For example:

```
$('.greatClassName').greatPlugin();
```

**From `greatPlugin()`, how can I get `'.greatClassName'`?**

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can access it through `this.selector`;

Example:

```
$.fn.greatPlugin = function() {
    console.log( this.selector );
};

$('.greatClassName').greatPlugin(); // prints .greatClassName
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside `greatPlugin()`, use `this.selector` for the selector, and `this.context` for the context.